# Why the QGraphicsPixmapItem exists offset when use fitInView() function?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicspixmapitem

I use fitInView() function to view the image pixels, but image pixels exists offset, how to solve this problem?

```
void QtGraphicsView::setViewRect(const QRectF &rect)
{
    if (m_viewRect == rect)
        return;

    m_viewRect = rect;
    fitInView(rect);
}

void QtGraphicsView::scaleView(qreal factor)
{
    const QSizeF &size = m_viewRect.size() / factor;
    if (size.width() <= 0 || size.height() <= 0
            || size.width() >= sceneRect().width()
            || size.height() >= sceneRect().height())
        return;

    const QSizeF &dsize = m_viewRect.size() - size;
    const QPointF &topLeft = m_viewRect.topLeft()
            + QPointF(dsize.width() / 2, dsize.height() / 2);
    setViewRect(QRectF(topLeft, size).toRect());
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can show a picture of what you indicate

Comment: hi eyllanesc，my picture upload

Comment: I think it does not let me understand, what I'm asking is that you provide an image of the GUI that shows the offset that you point out. Also what is `m_viewRect?, provide a [mcve]

Comment: 'm_viewRect' represents the rect for which the scene is viewed

Comment: I do not see the offset, also if you want help provide the MCVE

Comment: From my experience `QGraphicsView` has some trouble with pixel alignment on very high zoom levels. I never found a solution for this 'bug' in my projects.

Comment: @MartinHennings Using QGLWidget as viewport can solve this 'bug' but i don't want to use it.